# Use WWW and UnityWebRequest in the Editor Window plugin

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In Unity I have a custom window and I am trying to load an image from Amazon S3 and display it within the window. However, my function doesn't seem to execute. If I put a `Debug.Log` in the function it never gets logged, however, a `Debug.Log` before the function gets called (`LoadAvatarTexture`) does log. From what I understand is that `IEnumerator` doesn't work in an `EditorWindow` class, but works for a `MonoBehaviour` class. What can I do to make my editor window load an image?

```
public class MyEditorWindow : EditorWindow {

  Texture2D avatarTexture;

  [MenuItem("GameSmart/Player Manager", false, 0)]
  public static void ShowManager() {
    var window = EditorWindow.GetWindow(typeof(MyEditorWindow));
    window.titleContent = new GUIContent("Player Manager");
    window.minSize = new Vector2(400, 300);
  }

  void OnGUI() {
    var loadPlayer = GUILayout.Button("Load Player");
    if (loadPlayer) {
      Debug.Log("I log to the console just fine");
      LoadAvatarTexture("http://dev-avatars.gamesmart.com/default.png");
    }
    if (avatarTexture != null) {
      float aspect = (float)avatarTexture.width / (float)avatarTexture.height;
      Rect previewRect = GUILayoutUtility.GetAspectRect(aspect, GUILayout.Width(100), GUILayout.ExpandWidth(true));
      GUI.DrawTexture(previewRect, avatarTexture, ScaleMode.ScaleToFit, true, aspect);
    }
  }

  IEnumerator LoadAvatarTexture(string url) {
    Debug.Log("I do not log to the console");
    var www = new WWW(url);
    yield return www;
    avatarTexture = www.texture;
  }

}
```

Comment: 'my function doesn't seem to work' - why? Do you get an exception? What is not working?

Comment: Sorry, I mean it doesn't execute. I updated the question to reflect that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> However, my function doesn't seem to execute.

That's because `LoadAvatarTexture` is a coroutine function. You don't call a coroutine function like a normal function. You start it with the `StartCoroutine` function. For example, `StartCoroutine(LoadAvatarTexture())`.

Even starting it with `StartCoroutine` wouldn't work in your particular case because this is an Editor plugin and `StartCoroutine` requires instance of `MonoBehaviour` to work. You only get access to `StartCoroutine` when your script derive from `MonoBehaviour` but it doesn't.

**You have two options:**

**1**. Continue to have the `LoadAvatarTexture` function as a coroutine function which it is currently is but get instance of `MonoBehaviour` from the camera or any Object in the scene. I prefer the main camera since it's unlikely to be disabled.

Replace

```
LoadAvatarTexture("http://dev-avatars.gamesmart.com/default.png");
```

with

```
//Get camera's MonoBehaviour
MonoBehaviour camMono = Camera.main.GetComponent<MonoBehaviour>();
//Use it to start your coroutine function
camMono.StartCoroutine(LoadAvatarTexture("http://dev-avatars.gamesmart.com/default.png"));
```

Note that you must check for error before using the request. Below is your new `LoadAvatarTexture` function modified to check for error:

```
IEnumerator LoadAvatarTexture(string url)
{
    Debug.Log("I do not log to the console");
    var www = new WWW(url);
    yield return www;
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(www.error))
        avatarTexture = www.texture;
    else
        Debug.Log(www.error);
}
```

---

**2**. Another option is to make the `LoadAvatarTexture` function to be a normal (`void`) function instead of coroutine function then use `WWW.isDone` to determine when the request is done.

```
void OnGUI()
{
    var loadPlayer = GUILayout.Button("Load Player");
    if (loadPlayer)
    {
        Debug.Log("I log to the console just fine");
        LoadAvatarTexture("http://dev-avatars.gamesmart.com/default.png");
    }

    //Check if request is done then get the texture
    if (www != null && www.isDone)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(www.error))
            avatarTexture = www.texture;
        else
            Debug.Log(www.error);

        //Reset
        www = null;
    }

    if (avatarTexture != null)
    {
        float aspect = (float)avatarTexture.width / (float)avatarTexture.height;
        Rect previewRect = GUILayoutUtility.GetAspectRect(aspect, GUILayout.Width(100), GUILayout.ExpandWidth(true));
        GUI.DrawTexture(previewRect, avatarTexture, ScaleMode.ScaleToFit, true, aspect);
    }
}

WWW www;
void LoadAvatarTexture(string url)
{
    Debug.Log("I do not log to the console");
    www = new WWW(url);
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(www.error))
        avatarTexture = www.texture;
    else
        Debug.Log(www.error);
}
```

Comment: Option 1 didn't work for me, as `camMono` was always `null` even though there was a main camera. Option 2 worked, and loaded the image in my editor window!

Comment: Not sure why it is returning null for you. It works for me. The camera is not the only option. You can create an empty GameObject, attach an empty script to it then use it as a reference for starting coroutines. If you run into further issues, stick with solution #2 which works just fine for you.

Comment: `GetComponent<Component>()` instead of `GetComponent<MonoBehaviour>()` fixes the issue I was having in option 1

Comment: Then how do you the coroutine with `Component`?

Comment: I guess I can't, however it is no longer `null` when I do that.